# How to apply patches on Term Reference Tree

Tags: taxonomy-terms

while using [Term Reference Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) module it shows me following error. I have found the [PATCH](https://www.drupal.org/files/i18n_compatibility_rerolled-1514794-27.patch) for this error.

I am new to drupal. I don't know how can I apply this patch. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$vid in i18n_taxonomy_term_name() (line 461 of /home/lawand9/public_html/law/sites/spanish.lawandmoney.info/modules/i18n-7.x-1.11/i18n/i18n_taxonomy/i18n_taxonomy.module).
    Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 173 of /home/lawand9/public_html/law/includes/entity.inc).
    Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 350 of /home/lawand9/public_html/law/includes/entity.inc).
    Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$vid in i18n_taxonomy_term_name() (line 461 of /home/lawand9/public_html/law/sites/spanish.lawandmoney.info/modules/i18n-7.x-1.11/i18n/i18n_taxonomy/i18n_taxonomy.module).
    PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base.i18n_tsid' in 'field list': SELECT base.tid AS tid, base.vid AS vid, base.name AS name, base.description AS description, base.format AS format, base.weight AS weight, base.language AS language, base.i18n_tsid AS i18n_tsid, v.machine_name AS vocabulary_machine_name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} base INNER JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} v ON base.vid = v.vid WHERE (base.tid IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 ) in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 191 of /home/lawand9/public_html/law/includes/entity.inc).
```

Comment: Related: [Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base.i18n_tsid' when using Term Reference](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/147242/1908).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would take one second and google how to apply patches, you would come across this page: https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply. It explains how to apply patches.

Comment: yes,but how can i apply patch using command line. my website is already on server

Comment: You have to connect with ssh. If your server doesn't allowed SSH connection, you will have to apply the manually

Comment: ok,so i edited code manually first 4 error gones but not last one

Comment: You should open a new question. This hasn't problem isn't related to apllying patches. Also, if my answer helped you out, upvote it so that users know this is a legit answer