# Unknown column 'base.i18n_tsid' when using Term Reference Tree module

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n, database

I've installed [Term Reference Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) module to create hierarchical tree to select checkbox and it works fine in English website, but when I am using the same in my Spanish website it gives me following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base.i18n_tsid' in 'field list': SELECT base.tid AS tid, base.vid AS vid, base.name AS name, base.description AS description, base.format AS format, base.weight AS weight, base.language AS language, base.i18n_tsid AS i18n_tsid, v.machine_name AS vocabulary_machine_name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} base INNER JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} v ON base.vid = v.vid WHERE (base.tid IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 2 ) in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 191 of /home/lawand9/public_html/law/includes/entity.inc).

I dont know why it happens. Is it because of multilingual module or taxonomy translation?

Comment: Which Drupal are you using? 7?

Comment: Make sure you ran necessary updates (`/update.php`) if you upgraded one of the modules.